# Visualforce page: access from a guest

Tags: visualforce, redirect, remote-access, guest-user

In my org I have a public Site *SSLazio* (i.e., it is accessible from a guest not logged in Salesforce).
The Visualforce page JohnPage is in the **Site Visualforce Pages** list of the *SSLazio* Site.

Is there a way to access to the JohnPage from outside Salesforce without a login (exactly as I do with the Site)?

Comment: Interesting, can you explain in more detail what your requirement is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understand your requirement you need to add this page to **Guest User profile** and assign this page in site. Then you can access this page without Login.

**Note:** Make sure you also give access to all object to guest user profile which you are using in this page otherwise it will give you exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had already did what you posted.
I have understood where the problem was: I tried to access to the page in a wrong way. I had to insert in the browser:

> PublicSite/nameOfThePage

Anyway I think your answer could be useful to someone having that issue.